# Getting an ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1, but I get a warning on the pipeline and a successful/passed email

Tags: selenium-webdriver, gitlab, automated-tests, gitlab-ci, playwright

When a test fails, I get a warning on the pipeline instead of a failure and I get a successful/passed email instead of a failure.
This is my .gitlab-ci.yml below

```
stages:   
  - qa 

image:
    name: maven:3-jdk-11
    pull_policy: [always, if-not-present]

variables:
    MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=/.m2"

test_qa:
  stage: qa  
  script:
    - echo "testing against qa..."
    - mvn test
     
when: manual        
  artifacts:
        when: always
        reports:
            junit:
              - /target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml
        expire_in: 120 days
```

Image of my log, pipeline, and email
[image]

After the test concludes, I expected the pipeline to fail and the email notification to report the failure.
Instead, I am geting a warning and a passed email

Comment: Consider posting the log [as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your job shows the warning sign status, it means your job has [`allow_failure:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#allow_failure) set (in this case, because it is implied for jobs with `when: manual`), so the job failure doesn't affect the overall pipeline pass/fail status.

To resolve this, set `allow_failure: false` on your job.

Comment: That fixed it. However, I have several jobs that I would like to run manually, but adding 
allow_failure: false to all the jobs causes the other jobs after the first job to be blocked.
Can this be fixed?

Comment: @tedtrain if a job is not allowed to fail, it must pass for the stage to complete. By default, before a job starts, the previous stage(s) must complete. There's ways to implement DAGs that ignore stage ordering using `needs:` but it sounds like maybe you need a different solution to accomplish your overall goal (possible X Y problem). If your jobs are not actually interdependent, maybe consider having them all in the same stage. Consider asking a new question with all the details about your problem if you need further help.